# How do I achieve the following results using the PrinterWriter class from a text file?

Tags: java, exception, io, printwriter

My application here prompts the user for a text file, **mixed.txt** which contains

`12.2   Andrew
22  Simon
Sophie  33.33
10  Fred
21.21   Hank
Candice 12.2222`

Next, the application is to `PrintWrite` to all text files namely **result.txt** and **errorlog.txt**. Each line from mixed.txt should begin with a number first followed by a name. However, certain lines may contain the other way round meaning to say name then followed by a number. Those which begins with a number shall be added to a `sum` variable and written to the result.txt file while those lines which begin with the name along with the number shall be written to the errorlog.txt file.

Therefore, on the MS-DOS console the results are as follow:

> type result.txt

**Total: 65.41**

> type errorlog.txt

**Error at line 3 - Sophie 33.33 

Error at line 6 - Candice 12.2222**

Ok here's my problem. I only managed to get up to the stage whereby I have had all numbers added to result.txt and names to errorlog.txt files and I have no idea how to continue from there onwards. So could you guys give me some advice or help on how to achieve the results I need?

Below will be my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class FileReadingExercise3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fileInput = null;
    String a = null;
    int sum = 0;

     do {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of a file or type QUIT to finish");
            a = userInput.nextLine();
            if (a.equals("QUIT"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            fileInput = new Scanner(new File(a));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error " + a + " does not exist.");
        }
    } while (fileInput == null);

    PrintWriter output = null;
    PrintWriter output2 = null;

    try
    {
        output = new PrintWriter(new File("result.txt"));           //writes all double values to the file
        output2 = new PrintWriter(new File("errorlog.txt"));        //writes all string values to the file
    }
    catch (IOException g)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    while (fileInput.hasNext()) 
    {
        if (fileInput.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double num = fileInput.nextDouble();
            String str = Double.toString(num);
            output.println(str);
        } else
        {
            output2.println(fileInput.next());
            fileInput.next();
        }
    }

    fileInput.close();
    output.close();
    output2.close();
}
}
```

This is the screenshot of the mixed.txt file:
[image: mixed.txt]

Comment: Divide and Conquer. Use `nextLine` to read a line as String. Then go on deciding if that line starts with a number or a name and handle it correspondingly. Then read the next full line ...

Comment: According to the screenshot, your input is on one single line. We assumed there were `newLine`s after each dataset. That will make things complicated. Personally, I'd say your Input is broken and useless and urge the creator to create a valid Input file. But I guess the horrible input is the main task to be dealt with in this assignment ... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your while loop like this:

```
    int lineNumber = 1;

    while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fileInput.nextLine();
        String[] data = line.split(" ");
        try {
            sum+= Double.valueOf(data[0]);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            output2.println("Error at line "+lineNumber+ " - "+line);
        }
        lineNumber++;
    }
    output.println("Total: "+sum);
```

Here you can go through each line of the `mixed.txt` and check if it starts with a double or not. If it is double you can just add it to `sum` or else you can add the String to errorlog.txt. Finaly you can add the sum to result.txt

Comment: oh hey hi thanks for viewing this question for me. :D erm i tried to change my while loop to exactly yours but it doesn't work. the total is 0 while all the lines are added to the errorlog text file. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I tried this code in my machine and it worked, seems to be I am using different `mixed.txt` contents.

Comment: oh hey hi I just put in a screenshot of the file hope it helps. :)

Comment: oh hey hi so your input is in one single line? We assumed there is one line per "entry". That will make things complicated @Scorpiorian83.

Comment: @Fildor hi Fildor oh yes so sorry i confused everyone because when I pasted the contents in the text file it showed exactly like the one  on top of the question.

Comment: So the original Input is with or without newlines? That's important. If it hasn't got any newlines, we cannot separate entries with `nextLine` @Scorpiorian83

Comment: @Fildor erm I tried before printing to console with the `nextLine()` and they seems to be newline entries though.

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 ok, then they got lost somehow while copying to the Textfile for screenshot. Then the answer is still valid.

Comment: @Fildor yeah the `nextLine()` printed to console is `12.2 Andrew` but when I try to print `Double.valueOf(data[0])` it says there is a numberformat exception.

Comment: @user2065083 oh hey mate i just managed to get it working now but can i ask you a question regarding the catch exception code? I've just learnt about exceptions not long so I don't quite understand the purpose of yours? does it mean that for those which does not begin with a number the exception suppose to print to file? Thanks!

Comment: Yes correct, in try block we are just trying to convert `data[0]` to `double` and add that result to `sum`, but if `data[0]` is not of type `double` then we will get an exception, so we are just writing that complete line to the file pointed by `output2`

Answer (score 1):

you should accumulate the result and after the loop write the summation, also you can count the lines for error using normal counter variable. for example:

```
double mSums =0d;
int lineCount = 1;
while (fileInput.hasNext()) 
{
    String line = fileInput.nextLine();
    String part1 = line.split(" ")[0];

    if ( isNumeric(part1) ) {
        mSums += Double.valueOf(part1);
    }
    else {
        output2.println("Error at line " + lineCount + " - " +  line);
    }

    lineCount++;
}

output.println("Totals: " + mSums);


// one way to know if this string is number or not
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        return false;  
      }  
      return true;  
    }
```

this will give you the result you want in error files:

> Error at line 3 - Sophie 33.33
>   Error at line 6 - Candice 12.2222

Comment: oh hey hi thanks for helping me here can I ask you what is 0d stands for? Thanks!

Comment: `0` means value `0` and `d` means decimal. Here `d` is optional. You can refer the Java docs for Floating-Point Literals --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html, it says `A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.`

Comment: welcome, small correction here, `d` represents `Double`, not decimal.