# What's wrong with my split() and its regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, split, double

Part of my application I encountered this problem. The `String` line variable contains **12.2 Andrew** and I'm trying to split them separately but it doesn't work and comes with a `NumberFormatException` error. Could you guys help me on that please?

```
String line = "12.2 Andrew";
String[] data = line.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])");

System.out.println(Double.valueOf.(data[0]));
```

Comment: Check stack trace of NumberFormatException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at your `data` variable? It didn't split anything at all, since the condition never matches. You are looking for a place in the input immediately after a number and before a letter, and since there is a space in between this doesn't exist.

Try adding a space in the middle, that should fix it:

```
String[] data = line.split("(?<=\\d) (?=[a-zA-Z])");
```

Comment: oh thanks so much I just learnt about these regular expressions and just copied them somewhere from my research. Didn't know the space was important as well. Cheers!

Comment: Do you think you can have a look at my previous question relating to this issue? Thanks again mate!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485260/how-do-i-achieve-the-following-results-using-the-printerwriter-class-from-a-text

Answer (score 2):

If you print content of `data[0]` you will notice that it still contains `12.2 Andrew` so you actually didn't split anything. That is because your regex says:
*split on place which has digit before and letter after it*

which for data like

```
123foo345bar 123 baz
```

effectively can only split in places marked with `|`

```
123|foo345|bar 123 baz
                  ^it will not split `123 baz` like
                   `123| baz` because after digit is space (not letter)
                   `123 |baz` before letter is space (not digit)
                   so regex can't match it
```

What you need is to "*split on **space** which has digit before and letter after it*" so use

```
String[] data = line.split("(?<=\\d)\\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])");
//                                  ^^^^ - this represent one ore more whitespaces
```

Comment: hi there thanks for your information here can I ask if you could also help me on a previous question relating to this issue? Cheers!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485260/how-do-i-achieve-the-following-results-using-the-printerwriter-class-from-a-text

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 Answers from question you linked seems valid. What problem you have with them?

Comment: i'm using the solution from Mena at the moment it works right until the third line as it begins with a string and then double and it gives an exception from there.

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25486313/1393766) shows how you should handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Your split is not working, and not splitting the `String`.
Therefore `Double.parseDouble` is parsing the whole input.

Try the following:

```
String line = "12.2 Andrew";
String[] data = line.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
// System.out.println(Double.valueOf(data[0]));
// fixed
data = line.split("(?<=\\d).(?=[a-zA-Z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(data[0]));
```

**Output**

```
[12.2 Andrew]
[12.2, Andrew]
12.2
```

Comment: oh hey hi there thanks for helping me out here. Do you think you can have a look at my previous question relating to this issue? I'm very stuck on it. Cheers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485260/how-do-i-achieve-the-following-results-using-the-printerwriter-class-from-a-text

Comment: Using dot is not best choice. This way you will split also `123foo` on `f` which will give you as result `[123, oo]`.

Comment: @Pshemo I'd agree with you if there were any more cases, but it does work just as well with the provided input.